# Changing a template class to a regular class - C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public:
 virtual void func(T t);
 virtual void func2(T t);
 .
 .
 .
 virtual void funcN(T t);
}
```

Basically a lot of classes inherit form A, but T is always one of the 2 types B or C.

Currently every change that i make in the class causes a very long build.

Since T can be either B or C i want to turn the class into a regular class.

Any ideas how to do this change in a smart and clean way, without copying each function twice?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the Pimpl Idiom

Comment: Are the implementations of these functions in the `.h` file or the `.cpp` file? What is it that changes: the declaration of the class or the implementation of the functions?

Comment: That `T` can be *either* `B` or `C` is a stronger case for keeping the template than throwing it out. If `B` and `C` share a common abstract base then rolling A as non-template against that base makes considerably more sense in the context of your assessment.

Comment: How long is "a very long build", and is the build time primarily CPU-bound or I/O bound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use explicit specialisations. You keep the template, but you tell the compiler explicitly for which classes to instantiate it.

Change your header file containing `class A` to contain only the declaration of the class and its members (like you would do for a regular class). Then create a file `A.cpp` with the implementation of the member-functions of `A` and the explicit specialisations, like this

```
#include <A.h>
#include <B.h>
#include <C.h>

//... Implementation of A

template class A<B>; // explicit instantiation for B
template class A<C>; // and for C
```

and add this file to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Without resorting to hacks, such as using preprocessor to define shared portions of your would-be-template classes, you cannot avoid templates without introducing some code duplication.

If `B` and `C` do not share a common ancestor, you can introduce non-template classes for `A<B>` and `A<C>`, and inherit from them, as follows:

```
class AofB : public A<B> {};

class AofC : public A<C> {};

class SomeClass1 : public AofB { // this used to be A<B>
    ...
};

class SomeClass2 : public AofC { // this used to be A<C>
    ...
};
```

However, this is unlikely to change the speed of compilation.

If `B` and `C` do share a lot of common functionality, consider making a non-template version of `A` that uses the common ancestor of `B` and `C` polymorphically. However, this may not always be desirable, because it would force you to use pointers/references where instances of the template argument `T` were sufficient before.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to have `B` and `C` derive from a common base class, and have `A` operate on a pointer or reference to that base class:

```
class base {};
class B : public base {};
class C : public base {};

class A {
public:
    virtual void func(base &b);
    virtual void func2(base &b);
    // ...
    virtual void funcN(base &b);
};
```

This *will* avoid re-compiling B and C due to changes in A -- but at the expense of some extra cost at run-time. Specifically, A must work with B and C objects via a pointer or reference, which carries some overhead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, your real question is "How can I shorten build times when using this template class", not "How do I de-template this class".

Most likely the problem stems from having to recompile all files and not template instantiation, but even so the most obvious solution that comes to mind (given that the virtual functions of `A` work with both `B` and `C` objects as parameters) is to change from compile-time to runtime polymorphism.

Introduce a base class that's common to `B` and `C` and then instead of `A` needing to be templated, it can simply accept a pointer/reference to a `BC_Parent` object instead, utilizing the common interface to do the needed work. That should help compilation time immediately, but if more savings are desired you can now use the pimpl pattern to further isolate your changes from the client classes that use them.

In no case can you avoid a full recompilation when the actual interface of `A` changes.